# Need for git pull right after a git checkout for the first time

Tags: git, github, gitlab, versioning, git-checkout

From my understanding about git, every time I perform a `git checkout` one of two things happens:

1. The branch already exists locally and so the HEAD is simply positioned on the top of it.
2. The branch does not exist locally and so git "clones" it from the remote repository (let's just assume that git refs are updated)

However, for several times I perform a `git checkout` to a remote branch (that never existed locally) and I get an outdated content. Then I perform a `git pull` and new commits are received.

Does anyone had this problem too? Do you know why this happens?

Comment: Checkout doesn't clone... --- The branch may not exist locally, but the remote pointer should and so should the commit.

Comment: you're right. it is not a clone, that's why I wrote "clone" using quotation marks (my bad).
yes, the pointer exists locally thanks to `git fetch origin`

Comment: Right, then checkout just creates a local branch pointer to the commit and updates the working tree.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

You can avoid using `git pull` (entirely, or just sometimes, this is up to you).  You do need to run `git fetch` sometimes, and some other commands sometimes.

The way to keep this all straight in your head is itself a little complicated, but start with these:

- There are *two* repositories involved: yours, and the one at `origin`.  (There can be even more than two, but start with two, it just gets hairier if you add more!)
- *Your* Git repository has what Git calls a *remote*, which is essentially just a name: `origin`.  This name stores the URL for othe other Git repository.
- Each repository is self-contained.  Each repository has *its own* set of branches, tags, and so on.
- Any one Git repository can call up any other Git repository via some URL, using the Internet as a sort of telephone or messaging connection.  Using a remote name, like `origin`, is almost always the way to go here.  Among other things, it means you only have to type in a long URL once.

If you run `git config -l` (list all of your configuration) or `git config --get-regex "remote\..*"` you should see at least two entries:

```
remote.origin.url <some url>
remote.origin.fetch +refs/heads/*:refs/remotes/*
```

The first one is the saved URL.  The second one is some directives for the `git fetch` command.

#### Connecting two Git repositories

Since there are two Git repositories involved here, you have to connect them to each other now and then.  There are two primary Git commands for doing this, `git fetch` and `git pull`.  Both direct *your* Git to call up the other Git, so the difference is the *direction of transfer:*

- `git fetch` has your Git call up their Git and *get* things;
- `git push` has your Git call up their Git and *give* things.

What you give or take here are *commits*.  While commits *hold* files (by holding a complete snapshot), commits aren't files in and of themselves, so it's wrong to think of this as pushing or fetching *files*.  It's always *whole commits*.

But there is a huge wrinkle: commits, in Git, have to be *findable*.

#### Finding commits

Let's draw a tiny repository with just three commits in it.  Commits have big ugly hash IDs, which appear random (though they're not); rather than inventing some, let's use single uppercase letters.  This limits our pseudo-repository to just 26 ASCII commits (though maybe we could name a commit Ø in Norwegian, for instance, to gain a few more), but it's a lot more convenient.

A commit stores its *parent* commit's hash ID inside it, so that the commit *points back* to its parent:

```
A <-B <-C
```

`C` is our most recent commit, and it records the fact that `B` is its parent.  `B` records that `A` is `B`'s parent.  Since `A` was our first commit, it has no parent (it's a *root commit* in Git terms) and we just stop there.  But how do we find `C`?  The answer is that we use a *branch name* like `master`:

```
A <-B <-C   <--master
```

To add a *new* commit to our repository, we compute its hash ID—in our simplified drawing, this is just `D`—and write it out, setting its parent to the *current* commit `C`.  Then we *change* master so that it points to `D` instead of `C`:

```
A--B--C--D   <-- master
```

We never change any *existing* commit, and we don't really need to record the direction of their arrows: they always point backwards.  But we do change branch names, all the time, so we should write down their arrows, since they move.

Git therefore works *backwards*.  It always has the information about the *newest* commits.  It uses those to find older commits.  Git attaches the name `HEAD` to one of the branches, so that it knows which branch you're on.  When you run `git checkout`, one of the things it does is to attach `HEAD` to whichever branch you checked out.  I'll start including that below.

#### Remote-tracking names

Let's go back to the fact that there are two Git repositories involved here.  One of them is *yours*.  You have your own branch names like `master` and `develop` and `feature/short` and `feature/tall` and so on.  But there's another Git repository over at `origin`, and it has *its* branch names.

When your Git calls up their Git and obtains their commits, their Git has been finding their commits by *their* branch names.  What if their `master` and your `master` don't agree about which commit they should point to?  You've added `D` and they don't have `D` yet, so *their* `master` still points to `C`, for instance.

Your Git records *their* branch pointers by *renaming them*.  Your `origin/master` remembers their `master`:

```
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- origin/master
```

If they've added a *new* commit to their `master` since you were last in sync, that commit has a different (and unique) hash ID.  Let's call it `E`:

```
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C
       \
        E   <-- origin/master
```

#### `git checkout` will *create* a branch if appropriate

Suppose you have, in your repository, some series of commits, plus some names:

```
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- origin/master, origin/dev
```

If you now say `git checkout dev`, well, you don't *have* a `dev`.  But you do have `origin/dev`, pointing to commit `C`.  Your Git notices this and automatically *creates* your `dev` now:

```
        D   <-- master
       /
A--B--C   <-- dev (HEAD), origin/master, origin/dev
```

Note how the branch *name* is new, even though the commit is not.  The name `HEAD` is now attached to the new branch name.

If you `git checkout master` again, your `dev` continues to exist, pointing to `C`:

```
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- dev, origin/master, origin/feature
```

The only thing that happens is that your `HEAD` attaches to your existing `master` (and of course Git checks out commit `D` as well).

If you now `git fetch` from `origin` again, and they've added commit `E` to their `master` and `F` to their `dev`, with `E` pointing back to `C` and `F` pointing back to `E`, you get:

```
        D   <-- master (HEAD)
       /
A--B--C   <-- dev
       \
        E   <-- origin/master
         \
          F   <-- origin/dev
```

#### Putting this together

When you run `git fetch`, you have your Git call up their Git, list all their branch names and their commit hashes, and then your Git obtains, from their Git, any commits *they* have that you don't.  Your Git adds those to your repository and updates your *remote-tracking names*.

When you first `git clone` their repository, `git clone` makes a new, empty repository (like `git init`) with nothing at all, not even a `master` branch yet.  Your `git clone` sets up the remote `origin` with the URL and default `fetch` line.  Then your Git calls up their Git (`git fetch`), asks them for their branch names, asks them for the commits they have that you don't—which is every commit, of course—and puts all those commits into your empty repository, using only the remote-tracking names:

```
A--B--C   <-- origin/master
```

As a last step, `git clone` in effect runs `git checkout master`.  This *creates* your `master`, also pointing to commit `C`.

Each later `git fetch` updates all your remote-tracking names—your `origin/*` names—while obtaining the (shared) commits.  Your remote-tracking names therefore remember their branch names, while your own existing branch names are left alone.

Thus, if you `git fetch` before running a `git checkout` that will create a *new* branch name, your *new* branch name will be created from the updated remote-tracking name.  If you `git checkout` the name too early, you'll create it from the *old* value—the old hash ID of the commit you already have.

#### Using `git pull`, or `git merge`, or `git rebase`

The `git pull` command just runs two commands for you:

- `git fetch`, which does all the above: it obtains any new commits and updates your remote-tracking names, but never affects *your* branches.
- A second Git command, so as to affect your *current* branch.

Usually you ran `git fetch` because you expected to get new stuff from the other Git repository.  If you *did* get new stuff, you probably want to do something with it.  That means doing something with *your* branch(es).

There are primarily two ways to incorporate any work you have done and committed, with work other people have done and committed.  These are `git merge` and `git rebase`.  So it's pretty typical, after `git fetch`, that you want to use one of these two commands.

Which one *should* you use?  Well, that's a matter of opinion and there are different schools of thought about this.  I like to choose which one to use based on how much work I did and how much work they did and how those bits of work relate.  To do so, I have to *look at* the work they did.

Using `git pull`, you must decide in advance whether to merge or rebase, before you have a chance to look.  So I *avoid* `git pull`.  I run `git fetch`, then look, *then* decide what to do.  You can't do this if you use `git pull`: you have to figure out which to do, merge or rebase, before you can see which one you want.  Sometimes you might just know anyway, in which case, `git pull` is fine!

In any case, if you are using `git pull`, you tell Git which to do: merge (the default), or `--rebase` to rebase.  It then runs `git fetch` for you, and runs the second command—`git merge` or `git rebase`—for you.  And that's all it really does!<sup>1</sup>  It's a good idea to know how `git merge` and `git rebase` work, and I think you'll learn them much faster if you run them manually, instead of having `git pull` run them for you, but you now have all the pieces you need to make your own decisions here.

---

<sup>1</sup>Well, if there are *submodules*, you can have it recursively pull in submodules.  But that's another can of worms entirely.

Comment: This is amazing!

Answer (score 1):

Git checkout branch updates the files in the working directory to version stored in that branch.

To pull the remote changes you have to run git pull origin remote branch.

Comment: Can you give a more detailed explanation?

Answer (score 1):

git checkout doesn't clone anything from the remote repository. It at most points the local branch to the last head of the remote branch last time you fetched it. If there's anything on top of this last fetched head, then you'll have to fetch/pull.

Comment: From my understanding about `fetch`, only branch and tag references are stored locally. 

What you're saying is that those references are pointing to a specific commit that may be older than the latest one pushed by someone else to the remote repo?

Comment: Yes. Your local `remote/branch-name` is older than the actual `remote/branch-name` on the remote.